# What application is used to open link for installation?

Tags: software-center

Please forgive my ignorance but I am a Ubuntu novice, to say the very least. 
My question involves downloading and installing.  By way of example, I was on this page:

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/browser-plugin-gnash/

I attempted to download by selecting the red button which brought up a dialogue box which read "This link needs to be opened with an application."  Then it asks me to choose an application.  I select choose and several selections appear but I do not know what they are or what is their function.
Could someone please explain to me what application is utilized for this purpose and how to find it. I attempted to find the "software center" thinking that might be a good application to download a plugin but the "software center" was no where to be found in the list of available options.  Thank  you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the below icon on download and install [page](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/browser-plugin-gnash/).

   [image]
2. Select Choose option to install the package through available appropriate application(Software-center).
3. Select  `software-center` script from the path `/usr/bin` and press Open.

   [image]
4. Now, it will be opened in Software-center. Click on the **install** button to install the corresponding package on your system.

   [image]